# How to change the minSdkVersion in react capacitor project?

Tags: android, reactjs, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am building a project that runs on Ionic + react + capacitor. Whenever I remove the android folder and then run the command `npx cap add android` then minSdkVersion takes 21 default but I need 25, to solve that issue I need to change in variable.gradle manually but What I want is whenever I run command `npx cap add android` then SDK version should as I define somewhere.

Comment: go to android folder and edit `variables.gradle` file.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib, I don't want to change variable.gradle, minSdkVersion should handle outside of the android folder

Comment: Does anyone knows where it takes minSdkVersion 21 by default when I run the command ```npx cap add android```?

Comment: Why don't you want to change variable.gradle file? this is the setting your are looking for. this is how capacitor project works.

Comment: Because if some developer removes the android folder then.., so I want to manage it from outside of the android folder same like we add the config.xml file in the root path for Cordova.

Comment: No. Other Developer can't remove android folder. i was Cordova where native Platform were managed that way. in Capacitor your Native Folders(android/Ios) are  part of your project and it will go with your project to your source control and other developers will have same settings as you.

Comment: Same for me. I don't want to modify the `variables.gradle` file, as the `android/` folder is not versioned but generated by my `ionic capacitor add android && ionic capacitor sync android && npx capacitor-assets generate --android` command. I would like to have the option in my `capacitor.config.ts` file.